# Library javascript for making histogram

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, javascript, histogram

i work on asp.net mvc3 project , and i have to display histogram in view depending on data coming from action, can you suggest me any library javascript that can be easy to use and make good histogram, please any syggestion !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.highcharts.com/ - excellent integration and nice looking (free for non-commercial)

http://www.jqplot.com/ - open source, nice looking as well (free as in beer)

http://g.raphaeljs.com/ - another open source, well maintained

http://www.flotcharts.org/ - built specifically for JQuery (if that is what you are using)

Basically, take a look at these and others, find one that looks good and will easily plug in to your existing architecture and roll.

Comment: I like highcharts, raphael is pretty good as well.  Basically, any of these will achieve your goals, you will need to do a little evaluation on your end to determine which one of these meets your reqs. the best.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to sort the data into bins, take a look at [histogram.js](https://github.com/eoinmurray/histogram).

Answer (score 0):

##### 2023 open source alternative

If one is willing to decouple data binning from visualization, an alternative that is fully open source is to:

- Bin the data using [d3.bin](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-bin) (requires the the [d3-array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) library); a full example is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76113849/8929855)
- Visualize the binned data using ApexCharts.js (full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419893/make-a-histogram-in-apexcharts-js)) or Chart.js (full example [here](https://leimao.github.io/blog/JavaScript-ChartJS-Histogram/))