# Make a histogram in ApexCharts.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, histogram, apexcharts

I'm trying to create a histogram using ApexCharts (more specifically, React-ApexCharts, but I don't think it makes a difference).

Example of the output I'm after:
[image: expected_output]
The example above was originally created using Chart.js ([source](https://leimao.github.io/blog/JavaScript-ChartJS-Histogram/)). The blue shading for one of the bars is irrelevant.

Even though "histogram" is listed as one of the chart types in ApexCharts ([reference](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/type/)), I haven't been able to reproduce the example above. The issues I cannot solve are:

- Having `number of bars + 1` number of labels in the x-axis (i.e. in the example above there are 10 labels and 9 bars)
- Positioning the bars strictly between labels
- Having a tooltip that references neighbor labels for each bar (e.g. `Hours: 6 - 7` above)

Example code where I'm stuck: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wiles-8mbp3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something resembling your image, and the requirements you listed can be set this way:

```js
const yData = [5,8,24,16,32,42,30,17,11];
    const options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'visitors',
            data: Array.from({length: yData.length},
                (_, i)=>({
                    x: 0.5+i,
                    y: yData[i],
                    ... i === 4 ? ({fillColor: 'rgba(32, 120, 255, 0.4)', strokeColor: '#80afff'}) : ({})
                }))
        }],
        plotOptions:{
            bar: {
                columnWidth: "95%",
                strokeWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderRadiusApplication: "end",
            }
        },
        fill:{
            colors: '#ff4040',
            opacity: 0.3,
        },
        stroke:{
            width: 2,
            colors: ['#ee8080']
        },
        dataLabels: {enabled: false},
        grid: {
            xaxis: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            type: "numeric",
            min: 0,
            max: yData.length,
            tickAmount: yData.length,
            labels: {formatter: x => x /*Math.round(x)*/},
            title: {text: "Hours", offsetY: 70},
            axisBorder: {
                color: "#000000"
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: {text: "Visitors"},
            min: 0,
            max: Math.max(...yData),
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: "#000000"
            }
        },
        tooltip:{
            onDatasetHover: {
                highlightDataSeries: true,
            },
            x: {formatter: x=>{return 'Hours '+(x-0.5)+'-'+(x+0.5);}}
        }
    }

    const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

    chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chart" style="border: 1px solid #444">
</div>
```

If you listed the `Chart.js` code, one would get a better understanding of all your requirements.

Comment: The Chart.js code is linked in the OP ([copy of the link](https://leimao.github.io/blog/JavaScript-ChartJS-Histogram/))

Comment: @swimmer Sorry, I must've missed it, or used an early version of your post.

Comment: Meets all requirements! What I learned: (1) To build a histogram in ApexCharts.js, type `bar` works better than type `histogram`; (2) pass both `x` and `y` to the `series` data; (3) decouple the `xaxis` in `options` to have the bars between tick marks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation of the accepted answer by @kikon in React-ApexCharts:

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-raman-02e7qk

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";

export default function App() {
  const yData = [5, 8, 24, 16, 32, 42, 30, 17, 11];
  const series = [
    {
      name: "visitors",
      data: Array.from({ length: yData.length }, (_, i) => ({
        x: 0.5 + i,
        y: yData[i],
        ...(i === 4
          ? { fillColor: "rgba(32, 120, 255, 0.4)", strokeColor: "#80afff" }
          : {})
      }))
    }
  ];
  const options = {
    chart: {
      type: "bar"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: "95%",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderRadiusApplication: "end"
      }
    },
    fill: {
      colors: "#ff4040",
      opacity: 0.3
    },
    stroke: {
      width: 2,
      colors: ["#ee8080"]
    },
    dataLabels: { enabled: false },
    grid: {
      xaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: true
        }
      },
      yaxis: {
        lines: {
          show: true
        }
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: "numeric",
      min: 0,
      max: yData.length,
      tickAmount: yData.length,
      labels: { formatter: (x) => x /*Math.round(x)*/ },
      title: { text: "Hours", offsetY: 70 },
      axisBorder: {
        color: "#000000"
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: { text: "Visitors" },
      min: 0,
      max: Math.max(...yData),
      axisBorder: {
        show: true,
        color: "#000000"
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      onDatasetHover: {
        highlightDataSeries: true
      },
      x: {
        formatter: (x) => {
          return "Hours " + (x - 0.5) + "-" + (x + 0.5);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return <Chart options={options} series={series} type="bar" height={260} />;
}
```